# Rails 4 before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => ["some function name"]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

**The problem that I am facing with my :before_filter action is that,**

1. I need to allow a non-registered user to access the purchase page (0.0.0.0:3000/purchase) without signing into the site.This I accomplished with the bellow code in my Customer controller function like bellow and it workes:

   ```
   Customer_controller.rb
   class CustomersController < ApplicationController

   before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:purchases]
   before_action :set_menu

   .

   .
   end
   ```

The problem now is that, from the ***"0.0.0.0:3000/purchase"*** on submit should be redirected to ***0.0.0.0:3000/paymentpage*** after creating the purchase.

But on submitting from the purchase page it is then redirected to login page without going into payment page. How to allow the redirection to payment page without login ? I have tried the bellow by updating my code like bellow and it workes:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:purchases, :payments]
```

**But the problem is that, Now the payment page is also directly accessible.**

So how to allow the nesting of allowing the continuation of my workflow from one method to another method without going to check the **befor_filter :authenticate_user!** all the time, once if the user started his work from an accessible method defined in the  **before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:method_name]**.

Comment: There is a misspelling in your second code example: :paymnets should be :payments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have solved my problem by setting a flag with session variable status set to TRUE,to keep track on the user entered links are following the permitted path from one page to next page.

Here I will explain with my code:

First I have excepted the method purchase, to access directly for any user without being log in.

**Customer Controller**

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:purchases]
```

**create_purchase method**

Next in my purchase method at the end of the code I set a session variable with a flag set to true.

```
session[:@customer_permited] = true
```

And next in my payments method I will check for the status of the session variable if it is TRUE the user can continue use it without log in otherwise the customer will be redirected to the login page, so if a user try to access the link directly also will be redirected to the login page.

**payments method**

```
 if session[:@customer_permited].nil?
        redirect_to new_user_session_path, :flash => { :danger => "Please login to continue" }
 else
//my logic here.
```